# Filling next N rows in pandas with False when True found

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas Series with a bunch of booleans in it, and I'd like to filter for groups of `True` values.  In other words, I want to implement this:

```
def filter_noise_vals(series, N):
    # series: pandas.core.series.Series object with only True and False values
    # N: param that tells method how many subsequent True vals to set to False
    for val in series:
        if val: # value is true
            # set next N values in Series to False
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this without looping, but I can't quite figure it out.  If not, what's the best way to do it?

A pseudo-code explanation of this would be: every time a `True` is found, set the next `N` entries in the series to `False`.

Sample input and output:

```
(N = 5)                 (N = 2)
INPUT:    OUTPUT:       INPUT:    OUTPUT:
=================       =================
True      True          False     False
True      False         False     False
True      False         True      True
True      False         True      False
False     False         True      False
False     False         True      True
False     False         False     False
True      True          False     False
True      False         True      True
False     False         False     False
False     False         True      False
False     False         True      True
True      False         False     False
True      True          True      False
True      False         False     False
True      False         True      True
False     False         True      False
True      False         True      False
```

Comment: show a sample input and output

Comment: In particular, are you looking for groups of a given length? Or just any group longer than 1?

Comment: Any group longer than 1.  I will edit to show a sample input and output right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that it can be done without a loop. The intuition is that for any given element you don't really know whether it will be True or False, unless you evaluate all the previous elements.

But, as suggested by Yair Daon, it makes sense to only consider True values, rather than traversing the whole array, because this will definitely save you time if you are working with large datasets.

Then you can traverse the locations of the True values, and for those which are within N units from the last 'good' location, set corresponding values to False. Then update the 'good' location to be the next True location which is more than N units away from the previous.

```
input = np.array([True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, 
     False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True])
```

Get all True locations:

```
true_locs = np.where(input == True)[0]
```

Initialize the good location so that the first True location will be always selected:

```
last_true_loc = - N - 1
```

Traverse the remaining True locations:

```
for loc in true_locs:
    if loc > last_true_loc + N: 
        last_true_loc = loc
    else: 
        input[loc] = False
```

Results (with N = 5):

```
print input
[ True False False False False False False  True False False False False
 False  True False False False False]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `True` are dense, I would say your best bet is probably to just loop. If the `True` are sparse, you are probably better off finding the locations of `True` and looping over those. `numpy`
might be helpful.

```
import numpy as np
a = [True,  True, True, False, False, True]
a = np.array(a)
a = np.where(a == True)
a = np.ravel(a)
```

Now loop over the list `a`, replacing only elements that occur in it.